# Progress bar Start and Stop on Button Click using thread

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I have created a C# windows application in that I inserted the progress bar.

When a button is clicked the progress bar should appear and then it should start the process for some 2 to 3 seconds and when the process bar is completed it should be hidden.

I have used this code to solve this but its not working.

While the Progress bar is running, the label box that should be like "Generating... 45%" and after completing the label box should be "Generated 100%..", but when I insert the label its showing some errors.

Here is the picture before clicking the Generate button..

[image]
On Processing I Should get like this..
[image]
On Final Process id should be like this and the progress bar should hidden..
[image]

```
        ProgressBar1.Visible = true;

        if (isProcessRunning)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A process is already running.");
            return;
        }

        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(
            new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                isProcessRunning = true;
                for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                    progressBar1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progressBar1.Value = n));
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Generated!!!");


                if (progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
                    progressBar1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progressBar1.Value = 0));
                isProcessRunning = false;
            }

        ));

        // Start the background process thread
        backgroundThread.Start();
```

Comment: I cannot hide the Progress Bar after its generated..

Comment: you mean  , after 100% completed ? How about setting this progress bar's visible to false ?

Comment: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'progressBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. This error occurs.. s s correct i need to hide the progress bar @zey

Comment: Do you use `Backgroundworker` ?

Comment: There is a problem in the below code when i click the button for first time the progress bar runs one time and if i clicked second time it runs for 2 times and so on.. other wise the code is perfectly working.. @zey

Comment: I think so there is some problem in for loop for the below code.. because of the i value is increasing on every button click .. it runs many times.. @zey

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest you to use `BackgroundWorker` to show progress bar in C# winform .
Here is an example ,

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();       
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = "";
        label2.Text = "";
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
        bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgw_ProgressChanged);
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int total = 57; //some number (this is your variable to change)!!

        for (int i = 0; i <= total; i++) //some number (total)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            int percents = (i * 100) / total;
            bgw.ReportProgress(percents, i);
            //2 arguments:
            //1. procenteges (from 0 t0 100) - i do a calcumation 
            //2. some current value!
        }
    }

    void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        label1.Text = String.Format("Progress: {0} %", e.ProgressPercentage);
        label2.Text = String.Format("Total items transfered: {0}", e.UserState);
    }

    void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
         //do the code when bgv completes its work
    }
}
```

You can set your progress bar's visible to false in `bgw_RunWorkerCompleted` .
The following links will show how to use `backgroundworker`
[DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar)
[MSDN Reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b3aef3e-b698-4aa9-a1d8-50fe2cf24927/how-to-use-progress-bar-in-backgroundworker)
[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo)
Good Luck :)

Comment: There is a problem in the code when i click the button for first time the progress bar runs one time and if i clicked second time it runs for 2 times and so on.. other wise the code is perfectly working.. @zey

Answer (score 0):

This is the Code i am using backgroundWorker..

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();      
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label3.Text = "";


        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }


    private void btn_generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
       int total = 100; //some number (this is your variable to change)!!

        for (int i = 0; i <= total; i++) //some number (total)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            int percents = (i * 100) / 100;
            bgw.ReportProgress(percents, i);

        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        label3.Text = String.Format("Progress: {0} %", e.ProgressPercentage);
        if (e.ProgressPercentage == 100)
        {
            label3.Text = String.Format("Generated.. {0} %", e.ProgressPercentage);

        }
       // label2.Text = String.Format("Total items transfered: {0}", e.UserState);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
    }



}`
```

In this There is a problem in the below code when i click the button for first time the progress bar runs one time and if i clicked second time it runs for 2 times and so on.. other wise the code is perfectly working..

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();      
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label3.Text = "";


        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }


    private void btn_generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   new BackgroundWorker();
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
       int total = 100; //some number (this is your variable to change)!!

        for (int i = 0; i <= total; i++) //some number (total)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            int percents = (i * 100) / 100;
            bgw.ReportProgress(percents, i);

        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        label3.Text = String.Format("Progress: {0} %", e.ProgressPercentage);
        if (e.ProgressPercentage == 100)
        {
            label3.Text = String.Format("Generated.. {0} %", e.ProgressPercentage);

        }
       // label2.Text = String.Format("Total items transfered: {0}", e.UserState);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain what you changed and how this should fix ?